# Существуют ли "низкоуровневые" отладчики для JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, отладка

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать трассировку любого JavaScript кода? Т.е. я хочу чтобы JS-движок, который исполняет код не выполнил ни одну команду без моего явного указания её выполнить. Или может быть можно как-нибудь получить лог команд, которые выполнял JS-движок?

Comment: А можете рассказать, зачем вам это?

Comment: Уверен, что эти критические функции должны обратиться к серверу.... так вот на сервере и отслеживайте на корректность........... а то, если, к примеру, вы на клиенте напишите функцию покупки товара юзера за деньги, но на сервере не проверите остаток на счете, то это будет катастрофа......... за другими же не критичными вещами на клиенте следить смысла нет, кмк

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "JS-движок"?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov ну просто хочу допустим посмотреть как выполняется JS-код на понравившейся странице в интернете. Я что-то нажимаю, выполняется какой-то код. Если проводить аналогию с процессором, то я хочу видеть как JS-код выполняется на JS "процессоре", который в браузере установлен.

Comment: Вы совершено правы, @АлексейШиманский.

Comment: @Sublihim я подразумеваю ту часть браузера, которая исполняет код на языке программирования JavaScript.

Comment: @abg, в любом браузере сейчас есть devtools позволяющие использовать отладчик на странице

Comment: @abg вдобавок, если это V8, есть Debugging Protocol

Comment: @Sublihim за Debugging Protocol спасибо. Интересные возможности.